# How can I find the number equaling 2 in Riemann's zeta function?

Tags: riemann-zeta

I used some graphs but did not find the correct value,

$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{n^x} = 2 $$

what is the x value?

Comment: $x\approx 1.7286472389981836181351030102976914642$

Comment: $x\approx 1+{\rm arccot} \left({\frac {\zeta \left( 3 \right) }{55}}+\ln 
 \left( 3 \right) \right)
$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk , thanks for approximation, but what I wonder is this: if we consider 2 as y value, then do we have a general formula? for example if it was 3, what would be changed?

Comment: No it's not a general formula. Another approximation: $x\approx 1+\arctan \left( {\frac {276\,\pi}{137}}-2\,{\rm e} \right)$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk by the way your first approximation I guess has fault, right? Or you said radian or grad instead degree?

Comment: Note $\zeta(x) = 2,x> 1$ is important because $x$ is the abscissa of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} c_n$ where $c_n$ is the number of factorization of $n$ in products of integers $\ge 2$ where the order counts.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve $\zeta(x)=2$ we may use $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma+o(1)$ for $s\to 1^+$.
$\zeta(s)$ is decreasing and convex on $(1,2)$, hence Newton's method
$$ x \mapsto x-\frac{\zeta(x)-2}{\zeta'(x)} $$
with starting point $x=2$ (or, better, $\frac{3-\gamma}{2-\gamma}$) converges pretty fast to $1.72865\ldots$